# onhashchange cannot fully monitor the hash change event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, web

I registered an `onhashchange` event on the page like this:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', () => console.log('hash change!'))
```

It can monitor the hash changes that I manually input：

[image]

But no hash change caused by the operation page was found：

[image]

Is there any way to discover all hash change events?

And the page is developed by `vue`, so here is two listeners can be found：

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1807#issuecomment-336494269

Answer (score 0):

Vue-router is also listening for that event and only one event listener can be added to it.

But you can hook into changes in route on Vue side adding watch $route. Example from docs:

```js
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    $route(to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

Here to and from will be objects with hash property, which you and can compare and react to this change.